# With SAX, is it possible to exit from processing?

Tags: java

I want to read a specific node in an xml document, and I want to do it the fastest way possible and I believe SAX is the answer.

I'm using xerces right now, and I understand that the actual parsing is done using events.

So I have setup my start/end element events etc., and I want to know if it is possible to exit processing after reading a specific element?

i.e. once I get to a specific xml element, and read the contents, if it meets some criteria, I want to stop processing the xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you got what you want, simply:

```
throw new SAXException("I got what I want!");
```

Comment: interesting, but that seems like a pretty hacky approach, isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: As far as I can tell that is the only way using SAX, have you considered StAX http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo I understand, but if this is something I want to do regularly, and its not an exception per say.

Comment: Nonetheless, that is the way SAX was designed -- you can argue that in big picture it is not kosher, but that does not change the fact that in this context this is not a hack but the only way. Obviously SAX API could have been designed in a way to allow early exit (by using return values, say), but for some reason it wasn't considered a common use case.

Answer (score 2):

if you think throwing an exception with Sax is a bit hacky (I wouldn't like that as well), you should consider to use Stax instead of Sax. Tha main difference is that Sax uses a push approach, while with Stax it's your code that pulls events, so you have definitely more control and you can exit whenever you want.

I don't think there are such big performance differences between SAX and Stax. I completely switched to Stax because of the more control I have on the execution flow, which even means more readable code. Just give it a try!

Comment: but 'if' performance is the top priority, I might stick with sax.  The question is, does throwing an exception slow things down?

Comment: Whether it slows things down? It is a good question, but in this case also a non-question, because there is essentially no other approach to which you can compare (other than probably just leave the SAX parser to run to its end.)

Comment: @codecompleting I updated my answer. I don't think there are big performance differences between Stax and Sax. Of course, throwing an exception has a cost, but I personally wouldn't care so much about it. Stax just makes code more readable in this case, my personal opinion.